# Communicating symbols via linker sections

Tags: c, gcc, linker, attributes, sections

In C (x86 linux ELF, gcc/clang), is it possible to communicate symbol information through linker use/abuse? For example, say I have the following setup:

```
// foo.c
void a_foo_function() {...}
void b_foo_function() {...}

// bar.c
void a_bar_function() {...}
void b_bar_function() {...}
void c_bar_function() {...}

// master.c
void *array_of_function_pointers;

int main() {
    // do things with function_pointers
}
```

I would like `array_of_function_pointers` to be an array containing pointers to `a_foo_function` and `a_bar_function`. In this way, `master.c` could interact with functions defined in `foo.c` and `bar.c` without having to explicitly know about them. I recall seeing this done before by using custom sections (a la `__attribute__((section("name"))`), but I can't remember exactly what tricks were played.

From what I remember, the setup allowed `master.c` to stay unmodified, and any child could register some/all of it's functions via linker black magic, without having to write much, if any, boilerplate. Any gurus have some insight?

Comment: *I would like it to where function_pointers is populated with `a_foo_function` and `a_bar_function`.* Would you please rephrase that? It's not clear what you mean.

Comment: I tried rephrasing the question. Let me know if it's still not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to place the individual function pointers into an orphan section (that is, a section which is not placed by the linker script):

- [Orphan Sections](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Orphan-Sections.html)
- And the final paragraph of [Input Section Example](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Input-Section-Example.html)

You can declare these symbols `__start_NAME` and `__stop_NAME` as pointers to pointers, and use them to iterate over the section contents (the pointers stored there).

This approach is used in glibc for various purposes.  For example, [this commit adds libio vtable verification to glibc](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=db3476aff19b75c4fdefbe65fcd5f0a90588ba51).  The special section is called `__libc_IO_vtables`, and the start and stop symbols are `__start___libc_IO_vtables` and `__stop___libc_IO_vtables`.

Comment: Thanks, the missing piece of the puzzle was accessing the section pointers.